# Pass request on another server

Tags: php, proxy, cname, nameservers

how to pass request on another server before reaching mine ? like cloudflare ddos protection, is it with cname or text records ?

and what to do after adding a txt record or cname ? i didn 't try any thing that worked even a little bit i tried sending request with **redirect like**

```
<?php 
header("location: server.com');
?>
```

And not working case server is processing redirecting so its reaching server before redirecting, idon't think it need php or coding 
also tried to do it with cname but i don't know how to do it with it so it didn't work

Comment: You need to make your domain point to that server, then have it forward to your server.  Learn about reverse proxies.

Comment: how to point domain to server?

Comment: By setting a DNS record (A or CNAME)

Comment: DNS appears before any kind of HTTP(S) traffic.